# Is it possible to change the location of the default theme folder in VAADIN?

Tags: osgi, vaadin

I'm currently using vaadin 6 with OSGi.

I'd like to create a new theme, but since I'm using OSGi I can't add one under the VAADIN/theme folder since I don't have access to it.

I want to tell vaadin to look for my theme using another URL in my HTTP namespace.

Can I achieve this? The setTheme() method accepts only strings and I couldn't find anywhere if it's possible to register another default folder for themes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating your theme in a fragment Bundle and then attach it to the Vaadin bundle. This will practically merge/append the resources to the host bundle.
So you provide:

`VAADIN/themes/mytheme/`

in your fragment bundle and create the manifest with the

`Fragment-Host`

set to

Vaadin 6: `com.vaadin;bundle-version="${vaadin.version}"`

Vaadin 7: `com.vaadin.client-compiled;bundle-version="${vaadin.version}"`

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunally this is not possible.

From here : https://vaadin.com/de/book/vaadin6/-/page/themes.creating.html

Custom themes are placed in VAADIN/themes folder of the web application (in the WebContent directory) as illustrated in Figure 8.1, “Contents of a Theme”. **This location is fixed**. You need to have a theme folder for each theme you use in your application, although applications rarely need more than a single theme. For example, if you want to define a theme with the name mytheme, you will place it in folder VAADIN/themes/mytheme.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try pax for vaadin, it's not released yet and I'm laking some time to work on it more, but it should work for your use case. It tries to find vaadin applications and themes in your bundles.

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXVAADIN/Home

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out in a couple of weeks when I have more time. The fragment bundle solution works and I'm eager to move further.